# Firebase Real time database execute conditional queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Express and Firebase Real time database Admin SDK to manage database. I need to get all the tickets whose status are `pending` or `open` from the logged in user, but I am not sure how to get this data and I am not finding the solution in the documentation. In SQL would be something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tickets as t 
INNER JOIN users as u 
WHERE t.owner = u.id
AND (
    status = 'pending' 
    OR status = 'open'
);
```

In case you need to see some code to understand what I am talking about this is what so far I've tried:

```js
router.post('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const existingRef = database.ref('tickets')
        .orderByChild('owner')
        .equalTo(req.user.key)
        .orderByChild('status')
        .equalTo('open')
        .orderByChild('status')
        .equalTo('pending);
    const existingSnapshot = await existingRef.on('child_added');
    if (existingSnapshot.val() !== null) {
        return res.json(existingSnapshot.val());
    }
}
```

The previous code will return the tickets whose status are `pending` **and** `open` which does not make sense since there should be only one status per ticket.

So, what should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: i think the firebase isn't the best solution because the querying abilities are bad with it.

Answer (score 1):

The Realtime Database can only query on one child field at a time, so the query you're proposing won't work. You'd need to filter the results after fetching them, something like:

```
const snap = await database.ref('tickets')
  .orderByChild('user').equalTo(user.uid)
  .once('value');

const out = {};
snap.forEach(t => {
  if (['open','pending'].includes(t.child('status').val())) {
    out[t.key] = t.val();
  }
});

res.json(out);
```

You may want to consider using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) instead, as it can do more complex queries:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('tickets')
  .where('user','==',user.uid)
  .where('status','in',['open','pending'])
```

Comment: I have read about Firestore a little late, so I should change my whole code in order to migrate to Firestore. For now I will use the first approach.